# How to inject javascript into Chrome DevTools itself

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Ok, so just the other day I learned that you can inspect the devtools if it is in its own window(explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome)). I also learned that you can style the devtools with your own css by editing the Custom.css file in your profile on your computer(more on that [here](http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/)).

What I want to do is not only add css, but also javascript, via a chrome extension. I am very aware of [devtools pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html), but those do not do what I want. Pretty much I want to get a content script to run on the devtools inspector itself. I found one extension that does exactly this, but for the life of me I have not been able to replicate it(even when copy-pasting the code!!). The extension is the "Discover DevTools Companion extension" from Code School([on the webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/discover-devtools-compani/angkfkebojeancgemegoedelbnjgcgme)). They even [explain how it works](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/faq#extension-access), but I still have had no luck. That was the only extension I have found that does what I want. So I guess what I'm really asking is if its just me that cannot get it to work or if others that try are having trouble also.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usually, you cannot create a Chrome extension which injects code in a devtools page.
The "Discover DevTools Companion" extension <sup>from now on, referred to as DDC</sup> <s>is allowed to do this, because this extension is [whitelisted in the source code of Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/extension.cc&q=angkfkebojeancgemegoedelbnjgcgme&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=92):</s> (this is no longer the case)

```
// Whitelist "Discover DevTools Companion" extension from Google that
// needs the ability to script DevTools pages. Companion will assist
// online courses and will be needed while the online educational programs
// are in place.
scripting_whitelist_.push_back("angkfkebojeancgemegoedelbnjgcgme");
```

If you want to publish an extension in the Chrome Web Store with these capabilities, give up.
If you want to create such an extension for personal / internal use, read further.

## Method 1: Impersonate <s>the DDC</s> a whitelisted extension

The **easiest** way to create an extension with such permissions is to create an extension with the extension ID of a whitelisted extension (e.g. ChromeVox). This is achieved by copying the [`"key"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key) key of its manifest file to your extension's manifest (see also: [How to get the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest/21500707#21500707)). This is a minimal example:

#### `manifest.json`

```
{
   // WARNING: Do NOT load this extension if you use ChromeVox!
   // WARNING: Do NOT load this extension if you use ChromeVox!
   // WARNING: This is a REALLY BIG HAMMER.
   "content_scripts": [{
      "js": [ "run_as_devtools.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
   }],
   // This is the key for kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn (ChromeVox)
   "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDEGBi/oD7Yl/Y16w3+gee/95/EUpRZ2U6c+8orV5ei+3CRsBsoXI/DPGBauZ3rWQ47aQnfoG00sXigFdJA2NhNK9OgmRA2evnsRRbjYm2BG1twpaLsgQPPus3PyczbDCvhFu8k24wzFyEtxLrfxAGBseBPb9QrCz7B4k2QgxD/CwIDAQAB",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Elevated Devtools extension",
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

#### `run_as_devtools.js`

```
if (location.protocol === 'chrome-devtools:') (function() {
    'use strict';
    // Whatever you want to do with the devtools.
})();
```

Note: This method is truly a hack. Since the extension shares the same ID as [ChromeVox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn), both extensions cannot co-exist. And if Chrome decides to remove the whitelisted extension, then your permissions will evaporate.

Instead of filtering via the content script, you can also use the [`include_globs` key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#include_globs) to restrict the content script to devtools only.

## Method 2: Modify `resources.pak`

I suggest to go with method 1 if possible. When method 1 fails (e.g. because the extension is no longer whitelisted), use the next method.

1. Get `paktools.py`, `unpack.py` and `pack.py` from [DennisKehrig/patch_devtools](https://github.com/DennisKehrig/patch_devtools) (on Github).
2. Locate your Chrome directory containing `resources.pak`.
3. Run `python2 unpack.py resources.pak`, which creates a directory `resources` containing all files (all file names are numbers).
4. Locate the file containing a script which runs in the context of the developer tools. Add your desired code there.
5. Remove `resources.pak`
6. Run `python2 pack.py resources` to create the new `resources.pak` file.

Note: `resources.pak` may be replaced when Chrome is updated, so I suggest to create a script which automates my described algorithm. That shouldn't be too difficult.

If you're interested, you can look up the `.pak` file format in [`ui/base/resource/data_pack_literal.cc`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=ui/base/resource/data_pack_literal.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs) ([description in human language](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/agGjTt4Dmcw/uekdoo_cAxkJ)).

Comment: Well, that explains a LOT. Thanks so much for such a detailed and well laid out answer, I might just have to try those methods out for personal use, again thanks.

Comment: For anyone who wants to see the Chromium source file, it has moved [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/chrome_extensions_client.cc&q=angkfkebojeancgemegoedelbnjgcgme&sq=package:chromium)

Comment: DDC extension was removed, but chromevox is still there https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/extension_constants.cc&sq=package:chromium&rcl=1433662208&l=83 so one needs to use key `"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDEGBi/oD7Yl/Y16w3+gee/95/EUpRZ2U6c+8orV5ei+3CRsBsoXI/DPGBauZ3rWQ47aQnfoG00sXigFdJA2NhNK9OgmRA2evnsRRbjYm2BG1twpaLsgQPPus3PyczbDCvhFu8k24wzFyEtxLrfxAGBseBPb9QrCz7B4k2QgxD/CwIDAQAB"` instead

Comment: @auser Thanks for the heads-up. It seems to have been removed in Chrome 44 with https://codereview.chromium.org/1082363004.

Comment: Now that we are forced to inject CSS using an extension (`Custom.css` no longer works), can both of this tasks (inject CSS and JS) be done in one single extension?

Comment: @GetFree Yes, you can. You'll have to use a different key though (see two comments ago). Or modify resources.pak

Comment: i'm never getting past this logic gate: `location.protocol === 'chrome-devtools:'`. how does one have `location.protocol` not equal `http:`?

Comment: @Jason The developer tools runs at `chrome-devtools://...`, so `location.protocol === 'chrome-devtools:'`. Other examples include `https:`, `ftp:`, `file:`, `chrome-extension:`, `blob:`, `filesystem:`, `data:`, ...

Comment: yeah i understand that. i can just never seem to get anything other than `http:` to show up for protocol

Comment: @Jason The DDC extension is no longer whitelisted. Use the key as given by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042547/how-to-inject-javascript-into-chrome-devtools-itself/17044405?noredirect=1#comment49444751_17044405

Comment: I tried, but reloading my extension tells me: `Value 'key' is missing or invalid.`

Comment: @Jason That comment did not work because Stack Oveflow adds extra invisible Unicode characters to allow line breaking. I have edited my answer to include a usable key.

Comment: i figured that. tried to strip them but guess i didn't. put yours in, am still getting the same for `location.protocol`, which is `https:`. under what circumstances can you trigger it to make it `chrome-devtools:`?

Comment: i've tried loading, refreshing, closing and reopening dev tools... nothing works :\

Comment: @Jason Works fine for me, did you remove the extension, then load it again (the extension ID cannot be changed after loading it)?

Comment: i did :\ can only get it to say `https:`

Comment: @Jason Did you 1) put some code with visible effects in your script, and 2) open the developer tools? Keep in mind that if you use something like `console.log`, it is not logged to the page's console, but the console of the console. To debug the console, see the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21149275/938089.

Comment: dev tools are open. i threw a debugger inside the logic gate if the condition were ever true, never gets hit

Comment: @Jason Did you open the devtools of the devtools? If not, then you can of course not observe any effect. Try blanking out the devtools, or add `alert`, and you'll see some effect. Don't forget to reload the extension + re-open the devtools after every change.

Answer (score 0):

For those googlers who end up at this page (as I did) looking for something else, **this page** answers the question of manipulating DevTools ITSELF - not adding jQuery to DevTools, or injecting javaScript onto a web page.  For those, see here instead:

Inject jQuery into DevTools (Chrome or Firefox):
[Firefox DevTools: Automatically injecting jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246147/firefox-devtools-automatically-injecting-jquery/66287840#66287840)

Inject your own javascript/css onto any web page:
[How to edit a website's background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812723/how-to-edit-a-websites-background-colors/56812958#56812958)