# Tell Chrome which include files I want opened by default in devtools' Sources tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to tell Chrome to open certain include files in the devtools' Sources tab by default? I find it annoying to have to constantly manually browse the Sources tree to find the file I want to debug when it's the same file every time. I envision being able to add some sort of attribute in my `link` or `script` tags to tell Chrome to have the Source tabs open and waiting for me:

```
<!-- EditPerson.html -->

<link 
    href="EditPerson.css" 
    type="text/css" 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    chrome-source />

<script 
    src="EditPerson.js"         
    type="text/javascript"         
    chrome-source ></script>
```

Does anyone know of how I can do this, be it plugin/native ?

My question is sort of similar to [Programmatically Open JS/CSS File in Dev Tools 'Sources' Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18037595/740639), but I only want to pre-open tabs for files that have already been included in my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, DevTools will remember what tabs you last had open, but you can't really configure beyond that.
The good thing is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is really fast for opening up files, and it'll soon be getting some improvements in its scoring so most relevant files will be at the top.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've come across your website in the past, I forget why. I was just looking at your resume and saw you briefly went to University of Delaware. Small world: I grew up in Newark and got my Comp Sci BS at UD.