# JS: enabling export/import on client side (ES6 or using babel)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, include, babeljs

I want to export/import local files within an app directory:

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`actions.js`:

```
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
export const TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO'
export const SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER = 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER'
```

`main.js` (loaded from index.html):

```
import {ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER} from 'actions'
```

Now if I use javascript without babel, I will get:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

I use **Chrome browser version 60**. Shouldn't this version already support ES6? And by supporting, I should be able to use export/import?

I also tried with babel (using standalone babel loaded from `index.html`).

Then I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:4:16
    at n (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27049)
    at r (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27558)
    at e.src.i.(anonymous function).error (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27873)
    at XMLHttpRequest.i.onreadystatechange (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27316)
```

I understand that `require` does not exist on client side, but isn't that export/import (not NodeJS export) syntax for ES6?..

Do I need to resort to things like `webpack` for this to work?

According to this answer: [Trying ES6 imports with Chrome but it doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496479/trying-es6-imports-with-chrome-but-it-doesnt-seem-to-work) you need to enable `Experimental Web Platform` flag in Chrome and use `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`. But using it, stops loading anything. It seems browser just ignores such type. And even if this approach would work, then I guess I would not be able to use babel then, because it would use different type?

P.S. According to this: http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#named-exports-several-per-module it should work..

Comment: Yes, you will either need a transpiler (to convert ES6 module syntax to AMD `require`) + (dynamic) module loader, or a (transpiler +) bundler like webpack.

Comment: If you want to try the experimental Chrome support for modules: `'actions'` is not a valid clientside module identifier. You will need to import from something like `'./actions.js'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has achieved most of the es6 new features, except `import / export` has not yet achieved,for more detail:https://ruanyf.github.io/es-checker/

If you don't want use webpack to compile files，try:

```
$ npm install --global babel-cli
```

and then:

```
babel example.js -o compiled.js
```

finally,you will get the compiled files,which will support browsers。

plus,the key word `require/exports/module.exports` is a CommonJS specification,supported by Node.js.The file `https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js`used the CommonJS specification, so it will be reported errors on the browser side

Comment: If I compile (using babel), well it adds some missing semicolons, but syntax remains the same. So when I try to run compiled file, it throws same erros (with babel lib included or without).

Comment: use `import {ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER} from './actions'; ` rather than 'actions';because node will find this file from node_modules in current directory.

Answer (score 4):

`import` / `export` statements are now supported by [97+% of all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=javascript%20modules)

## How to use it

In the module (myModule.js):

```
const myVar = 'Hello !!';
export {
    myVar
}
```

In index.html

```
<script type="module">
    import myVar from './myModule.js'
    console.log(myVar) // output 10
</script>
```

[This is a good article on how to use it](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)