# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (Typescript for front end dev without framework)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

#### Description of project

I started a project which is a basic html canvas, no frameworks, and figured I'd use Typescript because of the type checking and because I had used it before with React.
I have the following basic HTML file to initialize the canvas and script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interpolerende Veeltermen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see, I load a script called `main.js` in the `build` folder. This `build` folder contains all of my transpiled Typescript code (with tsc).

#### Issue

When I start up a server, and open the website up in Chrome, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It refers to line 1 of my `main.js` file (which is the first script that my index.html calls). This line is the following import statement:

```
import InterpolatingPolynomial from "./curves/InterpolatingPolynomial";
```

#### What I've tried

I have tried tweaking my `tsconfig.json` file. It currently contains the following info:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["esnext", "es7", "es6", "dom"],
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I played around with different `module` and `target` options but without any luck.

I have seen some other questions about this issue, but none of the solutions seemed to work for me. Most used Webpack, which might be a reason for that. But if it appears that I missed a SO question that would help me, mark it as a duplicate for sure :)

#### EDIT

As mentioned at the beginning, the `build` folder holds all of the transpiled Typescript code. So yes, the file I refer to in my HTML file is indeed a Javascript file, not a Typescript file. I transpiled it using `tsc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `type= "module"`, in my script tag. That fixed the original issue:

```
<script type="module" src="./build/main.js"></script>
```

Due to some issues I faced with using `import` statements, I also decided to use a bundler: Parcel. This can be used to transpile TS to JS with no configuration. There is also no need to use the `type` property when using Parcel.

Comment: yes, Parcel would work well to solve the issue, as we discussed in my answer.

Happy that you resolved your issue.

Comment: Parcel was not the fix though. Changing the module type was! I just used parcel out of convenience :)

Comment: good to know, did you need to enable the experimental features flag in Chrome?

Comment: @StevenStark Nope!

Answer (score 0):

you can't run .ts directly, you need to compile it into a version the browser can understand; ES4.

please review the documentation here:

[Typescript and Babel](https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it is transpiled to javascript with tsc!

Comment: that error is common when the browser is trying to view raw TS source, could you confirm that you're including the compiled source in your HTML? 

your compiled output should not include anything like `import`, are you also using require.js properly?

this might help:

http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-amd-with-requirejs-tutorial/

Comment: What do you mean by `could you confirm that you're including the compiled source in your HTML`? 
I can confirm that it is using the `main.js` file in the build folder and not the `main.ts` file. The `main.js` file clearly lacks for example the types that are used in the Typescript file. So I assume that the transpilation did happen as planned. The tsc transpiler also did not give any warnings or error messages.

Comment: ok then I would look into require.js, because you should not be seeing the `import` statements in your bundled source code.

Comment: I do not see why though. `import` is supported in most modern browsers, including Chrome which I was using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: this is very newly supported in very few browsers, not something I would consider production ready. I have yet to use import directly in any of my work.

Comment: Well sure, but as I am using the latest version of Chrome, it should work just fine I'd think. How could I avoid tsc to transpile it for older versions?

Comment: I tried switching the `module` and `target` to "es2015" in my `tsconfig.json` file which shouls be widely supported as of now, but it still seems to keep the import statements.

Comment: it's one or the other, not both. You are either going to need to support only chrome, or compile your code to ES4 from the start. This is the exact reason I don't have any experience with your approach, as appealing as it first looks.

Comment: I don't know if Chrome still requires this, but in the past you were required to enable the experimental web features flag, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496479/trying-es6-imports-with-chrome-but-it-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a package and when that package is installed on another project, they get the error above, do the following:

Change the following in `tsconfig.json` file in the package:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

That will cause the package to be compatible.