# Trying to use Tagged template strings gives 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, template-strings, tagged-templates

I'm using tagged template strings in following code

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var pp="";
function tag(strings, ...values) {
  pp+=strings[0]; // "Hello "
  pp+=strings[1]; // " world "
  pp+=values[0];  // 15
  pp+=values[1];  // 50

  console.log(pp+"Bazinga!");
}

tag`Hello ${ a + b } world ${ a * b}`;
```

but it gives

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...(…)

On `function tag(strings, ...values) {`

Comment: What JS engine are you testing your ES6 code in?

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? Do template strings work in your environment without tags?

Comment: yes it does, I'm using latest chrome console

Comment: [Worksforme](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&code=var%20a%20%3D%205%3B%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0Afunction%20tag(strings%2C%20...values)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20var%20pp%3D%22%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20pp%2B%3Dstrings%5B0%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22Hello%20%22%0D%0A%20%20pp%2B%3Dstrings%5B1%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22%20world%20%22%0D%0A%20%20pp%2B%3Dvalues%5B0%5D%3B%20%20%2F%2F%2015%0D%0A%20%20pp%2B%3Dvalues%5B1%5D%3B%20%20%2F%2F%2050%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20console.log(pp%2B%22Bazinga!%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atag%60Hello%20%24%7B%20a%20%2B%20b%20%7D%20world%20%24%7B%20a%20*%20b%7D%60%3B)

Comment: Chrome doesn't support rest parameters yet: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-rest_parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the syntax error `Unexpected token ...` tells you, not the tag is the problem, but the usage of the rest operator. Try the following:

```
var a = 5,
    b = 10;
function tag(strings) {
  var pp="";
  pp+=strings[0]; // "Hello "
  pp+=strings[1]; // " world "
  pp+=arguments[1];  // 15
  pp+=arguments[2];  // 50

  return pp+"Bazinga!";
}

console.log(tag`Hello ${ a + b } world ${ a * b}`);
```

According to the [ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), you need to enable rest syntax via [the harmony flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011617/1048572) in the current Chrome.

Comment: Cool, it worked but didn't got how to enable rest syntax

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Put this link in the address bar and activate the highlighted option:  `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony`