# Why does my jsx code compile in js when I use npm start?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx

can you help me please. I use React and build my app by npm. Can you tell me why when I use "npm start" my jsx code transforms to js code in browser. But when I use "npm run build" it remains in the jsx format. It is not comfortable to debug my application using transform code. And I think that it's must be conversely when I build my app the code must be transformed.

My package.json is:

```
 {
  "name": "kb_frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.4",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.61.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

After answers below, I understand that I need to attach sourcemap to my "npm start" config. How can I do this?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX will always need transpiling to native JS be understood by current browsers. I guess what's happening when you run the build is that although it's still transpiled, a *sourcemap* is created which lets you see the 'original' or near-original in your browser.

Looks like your using create-react-app (great choice!).

Comment: Thank you for answer, Mark. Can you tell me, what shall I do to attach sourcemap for my "npm start" config?

Comment: The link that free-soul has provided below looks promising, it enables some beta features in Chrome. I suppose it depends on how much debugging you ned to do - I've found using the transpiled code's not too bad if you've nothing too tricky to do. The React Developer tools extension for Chrome is very useful as well (as is the Redux Dev Tools if you start to use redux).

Comment: Unfortunatly React Developer tools allow to debug elements only, not a source code

Comment: Sorry yes, I know, I was just suggesting them as another tool to help debugging in general.

Comment: No sourcemaps in dev is a known issue with create-react-app: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/109#issuecomment-234674331. If you really, really need them you may have to resort to another boilerplate environment for React, or work with webpack yourself. As you've already ran the build why not use that when you need sourcemap debugging?

Comment: I find the **SOLUTION** for my problem. You must open node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.dev.js and in module.exports replace `devtool: 'eval'` on `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'`. So in production config this param is setting by default.

Comment: Great, all the best!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have used [**`create-react-app`**](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to create your codebase.

- > *"`npm start` jsx code transforms to js code in browser."*

  Yes that is expected, because our browsers can understand only `js` and not `jsx`. Actually it is not just JSX, you have ES6 code as well, and they need to be transpiled to ES5.
- > *"when I use `npm run build` it remains in the jsx format"*

  I don't think so. All your JavaScript files are bundled, transpiled and minified, and will be stored inside `build/static/js/`
- > *"It is not comfortable to debug my application using transform code."*

  Yes unfortunately, if you're debugging in browser, you will have to deal with pure JavaScipt.

  But don't worry yet, you have Source Maps FTW! Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011617/5069226 which explains how to enable some experimental JavaScript features in Chrome Dev Tools for debugging your code with Source Maps.