# TypeScript compilerOptions "unexpected token import"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Falieson/react15-meteor1.5/blob/3a7c15d13d1d1e543d0165c80864c3449509e524/tsconfig.json) when I change the compilerOptions.module from 'commonjs' to 'es6' or 'esnext' I get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" for any of my instances of
`import * as React from 'react'`

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: What browser are you using?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Browser is Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You left out the browser *name*.

Comment: D'oh. Fixed. it's THE browser (lol)

Comment: I had a good laugh.  In Chrome, I *think* you have to turn on ES6 modules (experimental feature).  This is somewhere in `chrome:flags`.  To be honest i didn't look into this too deeply when we started with TS and Babel at work, since we must target IE which has terrible support for ES6.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008366/using-ecmascript-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Amy said, `Import` & `Export` keywords are very new in JavaScript, their introduction starts with the new ES6 standard and the implementation for each browser is non-existent or partially implemented.

As wrote in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), import & export are currently used with CommonJS/AMD.

The combination of this two situations throws sometimes a **SyntaxError** depending on your TSConfig and/or your browser.

**What I suggest**

***You want to use new ES6 standard***

You keep your browser up to date and you refer to the @Amy provided a link to know about `Import` & `Export` implementation for each browser.

***You don't want to use new ES6 standard***

You come back to `AMD` or `CommonJS` in your `TSConfig` file. With this solution you will need to use RequireJS to manage the `Import` & `Export` or to bundle your Typescripts file using **Webpack** Or **Browserify**.

***My Opinion***

If your code is only for learning or for fun, you can stay with the new ES6 standard.

If it is for production, I suggest to use Webpack, which is difficult to handle but very powerful.

Comment: If I use module="es6" (or esnext) and target="es5" shouldn't a transpile happen for import/export ?
is there some recommendation about where typescript compile ends and babel transpile picks up?

Comment: Webpack is always a great suggestion, unfortunately this is a MeteorJS project

Comment: @Falieson if the target is es6, that's the generated result.  Same with es5.  You can then run that through babel.  Here at work we use es5 as the target since we must target IE and run it through babel anyway for other reasons.  No real need to generate es6 if we're just gonna bring it back down to es5.

Comment: I'm new to TS but I'm used to using babel. for this exercise repo I'm trying to keep it simple with just {presets: ["stage-1", "react"]} . Maybe there's some babel features I'm used to having @amy that you are using which fixes the transpile of the build?

My (seemingly wrong) understanding of module & target is, "Module" = the ecma you can write which TS will understand, "Target" = what typescript builds down to

Comment: @Falieson Honestly I'd ask a new question regarding that.  I'd answer if I could.  I haven't used react.  We have `module='none'` and `target='es5'` in our TsConfig.json.  Again, I'd ask separately, I'm not knowledgeable enough on this particular topic to offer assistance with confidence.

Comment: Thanks @Amy, I'll do that