# How to catch timeline data from chrome debugging API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

**Task:** Goal is to get all the functions which are triggered by installed extensions.

**Expected Output:** Javascript function calls, similar to what appears in timeline panel.

**Description:** As mentioned above I want to get the timeline data from chrome. For that I am using timeline feature of [chrome remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/tot/timeline) to get timeline data using [chrome javascript debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger). I am starting a debuger with following code:

`chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabid }, version, onAttach.bind(null,tabid);
 chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabid }, "Tracing.start");`

However when I ran this code I get an error which states that timeline is deprecated, use tracing. Although official documentation haven't mentioned that timeline is deprecated. I have also tried tracing which removes the error but still no event is captured. Is there any issue of flags?

---

After reading code of [Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc?hl=en), I found out that **chrome.activityLogPrivate** API to log all the events by different extensions. However, I am not able to run it by calling inside my extension, it remains undefined. I am not able to find documentation of this extension also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stable [1.1 Debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index) has no "Tracing", however, the ["tip of the tree" docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/) say exactly this:

> Timeline domain is deprecated. Please use Tracing instead.

It should be a warning only, since:

> As of Google Chrome 31, we commit to supporting v1.1. All subsequent 1.* versions of the protocol are going to be backwards compatible with 1.1. Our protocol backwards compatibility commitment is:
>
> - No commands or events are removed from the protocol.
> - No required parameters are added to the commands.
> - No required parameters are removed from command responses or events.

So your commands *should* work normally.

---

`chrome.activityLogPrivate` API is what it says on the tin - *private*. It is only enabled for specific whitelisted extensions in Chrome's code, and it's not publicly documented.

So no, you cannot use it unless you use hacks [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044405/934239), which are not guaranteed to work.