# NodeJS debugger stops (breaks) at first line on app.js on my SailsJS app

Tags: node.js, debugging, sails.js

when I run `node debug app`, it breaks on `app.js:1`, so I have to manually continue de execution until the first debugger breakpoint.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Try this: `node --debug app`

Comment: That only sets up debugger to listen to port 5858, but doesn't start the node debugger 'client'(where you can stop in breakpoints)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable in the node debugger "break on first line"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420374/how-to-disable-in-the-node-debugger-break-on-first-line)